# How to create console application project with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to Visual Studio, after installation completed, I tried to make a Console project but it does not show me the option for creating one:

[image: capture]

As you can see even after my search about Console, it does not appear anything.

So my question is, how can I create a Console application in this situation?

Note that my Visual Studio is 2019 version and Enterprise.

Comment: Did you read the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: Review the "workloads" you've installed. You probably missed [something like ".NET Desktop Development"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on "Install more tools and features" and install the items you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

During installation of Visual Studio, make sure you install the necessary dependency framework that is .NET Framework is installed as well as it components